# HTML emails sending as HTML code

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-headers

I'm using Amazon AWS SES. This is how I send emails:

```
    $request = array();
    $request['Source'] = $row['emailfromname'] . " <{$verifyemail[0]}>";
    $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = $to;
    $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = $row['emailsubject'];
    $request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $row['emailbody'];

    try {
        $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
        $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
    ...
```

So it's pretty basic.

My problem is that some emails are sending as HTML. Here is an example of an offender:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    <html><body><p><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 11pt; font-size: 11pt; color: #333333;">Hi Name,</span></p>
    <hr><span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif"><b>From:</b> sender@sender.com.au<br><b>Sent:</b> Thursday, 9 March 2017 10:51 AM<br><b>To:</b> receiver@receiver.com.au<br><b>Subject:</b> Enquiry for ID: 98419081886, 123 Fake Street,
     Docklands, Vic 3008, Listing Agent Leasing Consultant</span><br><br><div id="message" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">

        <h1 class="header">
           <img src="http://www.test.com/logo.png" style="border: 0; width: 258px;"><div class="header-separator" style="height: 4px; background-color: #e4002b; width: 100%; margin-top: 17px;"></div>
        </h1>





        <p style="margin: 0;">You have received a new enquiry for</p>
        <br><p style="margin: 0;"> id: 98419081886</p>

        <div class="footer" style="margin-top: 1em; padding: 5px; background: #999999; color: #fff;">
    Message sent from <a href="http://www.test.com.au" style="color: #fff;">www.test.com.au</a>    </div>

    </div></body></html>
```

It sends in plain text as HTML code with the weird header info. This is my Outlook 2010 email received:

```
 Docklands, Vic 3008, Listing Agent Leasing Consultant
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 11pt; font-size: 11pt; color: #333333;">Hi Name,</span></p> <hr><span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif"><b>From:</b> sender@sender.com.au<br><b>Sent:</b> Thursday, 9 March 2017 10:51 AM<br><b>To:</b> receiver@receiver.com.au<br><b>Subject:</b> Enquiry for ID: 98419081886, 123 Fake Street,  Docklands, Vic 3008, Listing Agent Leasing Consultant</span><br><br><div id="message" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">

    <h1 class="header">
       <img src="http://www.test.com/logo.png" style="border: 0; width: 258px;"><div class="header-separator" style="height: 4px; background-color: #e4002b; width: 100%; margin-top: 17px;"></div>
    </h1>





    <p style="margin: 0;">You have received a new enquiry for</p>
    <br><p style="margin: 0;"> id: 98419081886</p>

    <div class="footer" style="margin-top: 1em; padding: 5px; background: #999999; color: #fff;">
Message sent from <a href="http://www.test.com.au" style="color: #fff;">www.test.com.au</a>    </div>

</div></body></html>
```

The thing that's really confused me, however, is that other very similar emails send with no issues at all!

I'm guessing there's a clue in that the first line of the output reads `Docklands, VIC 3008 ...` But even if I remove that line-break, the space and the comma (so it reads `123 Fake StreetDocklands`), the output stills starts with `Docklands...` including the space at the beginning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling sheepish and annoyed... After leading myself on a wild goose chase, I found my problem. It's so trivial that I was going to delete this question, but I won't in the hope it helps other SES users.

My subject had a line-break in it!

I'm not sure how or why Amazon lets this cause a problem for the email body, but it does.